# PHP Form data validation issue

Tags: php, forms, validation

I am making a basic content management system and I have got stuck with the validation of data being entered into a form.

For example, one form is to edit the name of a subject (in the navigation menu). The form contains a few different pieces of data but the main focus is the "menu_name" field (name of subject).

On form submission data in "menu_name" should be checked to ensure it is not empty and if it is then give an error. What is happening is that the form validation doesn't seem to be working as when I enter nothing the script continues to edit the subject name, in this case making it blank.

This is the script that is executed on form submission:

```
if (isset($_POST['submit']))
{
    // Process the form

    // Validations
    $required_fields = array("menu_name", "position", "visible");
    validate_presences($required_fields);

    $fields_with_max_lengths = array("menu_name" => 30);
    validate_max_lengths($fields_with_max_lengths);

    // If errors occured, redirect
    if(empty($errors))
    {
        // Perform update

        // Assign POST data to variables
        $id = $current_subject["id"];
        $menu_name = mysql_prep($_POST["menu_name"]);
        $position = (int) $_POST["position"];
        $visible = (int) $_POST["visible"];

        // 2. Perform database query
        $query = "UPDATE subjects SET ";
        $query .= "menu_name = '{$menu_name}', ";
        $query .= "position = '{$position}', ";
        $query .= "visible = '{$visible}' ";
        $query .= "WHERE id = {$id} ";
        $query .= "LIMIT 1";
        $result = mysqli_query($connection, $query);

        if ($result && mysqli_affected_rows($connection) >= 0) 
        {
            // Success
            $_SESSION["message"] = "Subject updated.";
            redirect_to("manage_content.php");
        }
            else
        {
            // Failure
            $message = "Subject update failed.";
        }
    }

}
```

The data is then checked by two custom validation functions as you can see, the second one is not my concern but the first function validate_presences(), here is the function:

```
function validate_presences($requried_fields)
{
    GLOBAL $errors;

    foreach($required_fields as $field)
    {
        $value = trim($_POST[$field]);
        if (!has_presence($value))
        {
            $errors[$field] = fieldname_as_text($field) . " can't be blank";
        }
    }
}
```

You can see there that it references the has_presence() function, which is:

```
function has_presence($value)
{
    return isset($value) && $value !== "";
}
```

If anyone has any ideas on what is wrong, any help is appreciated!
Just ask if you need some more information.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Have you defined the `$errors` variable before calling the validation functions?

Comment: $errors = array(); is defined at the start of the validation functions page.

Comment: Try return isset($value) && !empty($value); in the has_presence function

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you just return the error array instead of making it global? I think it will resolve your problem instantly ;)

```
function validate_presences($requried_fields)
{
    $errors = array();

    foreach($required_fields as $field)
    {
        $value = trim($_POST[$field]);
        if (!has_presence($value))
        {
            $errors[$field] = fieldname_as_text($field) . " can't be blank";
        }
    }
    return $errors;
}
```

Now set `$errors = validate_presences($required_fields);` and your ready to go!

Comment: The $errors = array(); is defined at the top of the validation functions page. Plus the same array is used by other pages and functions.

Answer (score 0):

It's not recommended to use variables in a global way like this. Rather pass the errors variable by reference to the validation functions.

```
$errors = array();

function validate_presences($requried_fields, &$errors)
{
    foreach($required_fields as $field)
    {
        $value = trim($_POST[$field]);
        if (!has_presence($value))
        {
            $errors[$field] = fieldname_as_text($field) . " can't be blank";
        }
    }
}

$required_fields = array("menu_name", "position", "visible");
validate_presences($required_fields, $errors);

$fields_with_max_lengths = array("menu_name" => 30);
validate_max_lengths($fields_with_max_lengths, $errors);

// If errors occured, redirect
if(empty($errors))
{
```

Comment: What affect can it have if done in the global way compared to passing it in?

Comment: Using it this way you are guaranteed that you always use the same reference of $errors. If you use it in the global way in lots of functions, one function might change the value of the variable in a way you don't want in that case (E.G clearing the value)

Comment: Makes sense, I will give it a go, when passing the variable in, should it be &$errors or $errors?

Comment: Tried it, it still fails the validation

Comment: It should be &$errors, so you pass the variable by reference, otherwise you will need return $errors in the function

Comment: Ok, I will give that a go

Comment: Tried it, it caused errors because it was not receiving the 2nd value when the function was called.

Comment: You should pass the $errors variable to the function as the second parameter, this is a very basic concept in php